# Euler-lagrange equation isn't unique

Tags: multivariable-calculus, classical-mechanics

If L is a Lagrangian for a system of n degrees of freedom satisfying Lagrange's equations, show by direct substitution that

$L` = L + \frac{dF(q_1,...,q_n,t)}{dt}$ also satisfies Lagrange's equation where F is any arbitrarily, but differentiable function of its arguments.

So I think I got everything correct except I don't know why the last step vanishes ?

$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial M}{\partial \dot{q_j}} - \frac{\partial M}{\partial q_j} = \frac{d}{dt}*(\frac{\partial(L + dF(q_1,...,q_n,t)/dt)}{\partial \dot q_j}) - \frac{\partial(L + dF(q_1,...,q_n,t)/dt)}{\partial \dot q_j}$

=$ (\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot q_j} - \frac{\partial L}{\partial q_j}) +\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_j}(\frac{dF(q_1,...,q_n,t)}{dt})) -(\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}(\frac{dF(q_1,...,q_n,t)}{dt})) $ (Eq 1)

By chain rule we have 
$\frac{dF}{dt} = \Sigma_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}\dot{q_i} \ + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$

Notice since L satisfies E-L equation the first two components of equation 1 vanishes. So equation 1 becomes

$\frac{d}{dt}(\frac{\partial}{\partial \dot q_j}(\Sigma_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}\dot{q_i} \ + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t})) -(\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}(\Sigma_i \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}\dot{q_i} \ + \frac{\partial F}{\partial t})) $ (Eq 2)

So why is (Eq 2) = 0 ? Can someone explain ?

Answer (score 1):

Perform the partial derivative with respect to $\dot q_i$. Since $F$ doesn't depend on $\dot q_i$, the first term is simply

$$
\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\frac{\partial F}{\partial q_j}\;.
$$

You can apply the chain rule just like you applied it for $\frac{\mathrm dF}{\mathrm dt}$ to find that this corresponds to what's subtracted in the second term. (Note that partial derivatives commute.)

Comment: is it true that $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}*\frac{\partial F}{\partial t} = 0$?

Comment: Yeah that is my problem how can I simplify the second term ?

Comment: can you care to explain a little more as when I expanded and used partial derivatives commute I got the following  $\Sigma_i \ \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_i}\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\dot q_i + \frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}$

Comment: @Illustionist: When you expanded what?

Comment: when I expanded the second terms that is I distributed the $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}$

Comment: and I used commutativity of partial derivatives that you mentioned

Comment: @Illustionist: I think you misunderstood what commutativity of the partial derivatives means. It means that (given suitable assumptions on differentiability)
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}F(x,y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}F(x,y)\;.$$It doesn't mean applying the partial derivative only to the second factor in a product, as you did. In fact applying it to that factor doesn't yield a contribution, since $\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j}\dot q_i=0$. You need to apply the derivative to the other factor; then commuting will make the two terms cancel.

Comment: why will make it cancel ?

Comment: $\frac{\partial F}{\partial t}\frac{\partial}{\partial q_j} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} \frac{\partial F}{\partial q_j}$ why is that equal to zero?

Comment: @Illustionist: I didn't say one of the terms is zero; I said the two terms will cancel. By "terms" I meant the same thing as I meant above: the two terms that are subtracted from each other in your Eq 2 -- which is, by the way, an expression, not an equation -- precision is worth a lot in math.

Comment: @Illustionist: P.S.: I just noticed that you still have the commutation wrong. Please look at the equation that I provided above to explain what commutation of partial derivatives is, and try to understand why this is something completely different from what you're doing. The key point here is that in my equation the function symbol always comes after both derivatives, on both sides of the equation, whereas you're "commuting" derivatives past the function symbol.